# Select a default alsa PCM (not card) via environment variable

Tags: linux, alsa, audio

I often use a headset, to select if using the headset or
the normal soundcard I use a environment variable thanks
to this code in ~/.asound.rc:

```
@args.CARD {
  type string
  default {
    @func getenv
    vars {
      0 ALSA_CARD
    }
    default {
      @func refer
      name 'defaults.pcm.card'
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the new headset (hw:Set) has reversed channels so I
created a pcm to fix, adding those lines to ~/.asoundrc:

```
pcm.swapped {
    type  route
    slave {
        pcm "hw:Set"
    }
    ttable.0.1   1
    ttable.1.0   1
}


pcm.HeadsetSwapped {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "pcm.swapped"
  }
}
```

The pcm works, but how can I decide to use it via environment
variable? At the moment the env variable only accepts card names.
It is probably something around the -- name 'defaults.pcm.card' --
line, but I cannot fix it.

I know I can change pcm.HeadsetSwapped to pcm.!default,
but I would like to avoid to edit the file each time
I want to start a program...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this, and set the environment variable `MY_DEVICE` to either `hw` or `swapped`:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        @func getenv
        vars [ MY_DEVICE ]
        default "hw"
    }
}
pcm.swapped {
    type route
    slave.pcm "hw:Set"
    ttable.0.1 1
    ttable.1.0 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. And it is well readable, uncommon for alsa related stuff.

Comment: Hint: If you hit "Device or resource busy" with default "hw", try default "dmix". I just felt into that trap.